# How to use an object instantiated by a different ClassLoader

Tags: java, jar, applet, classloader, classcastexception

My applet needs classes which are part of external jars (signed jars) and native libraries. I deploy these jars within my applet.jar. To load classes from those jars I found [com.jdotsoft.jarloader.JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) class to be useful. I first build a console app to test the functionality of my applet and the JarClassLoader works fine for me. 
Next I wrote MyApplet class with two additional public methods, let's say action1() and action2(). And, as described by the JarClassLoader, I wrote a MyAppletLauncher class. (see code below). To get a reference to the MyApplet object, instantiated by the JarClassLoader I added the getApplet() method to the JarClassLoader class.

MyApplet.java:

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
    public void init()    { ... }
    public void start()   { ... }
    public void stop()    { ... }
    public void destroy() { ... }

    public String action1() {
        ...
    }
    public int action2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

MyAppletLauncher.java:

```
public class MyAppletLauncher extends Applet {
    private JarClassLoader jcl;
    public void init() {
        jcl = new JarClassLoader();
        jcl.initApple("MyApplet", this);
    }
    public void start() {
        jcl.startApplet();
    }
    public void stop() {
        jcl.stopApplet();
    }
    public void destroy() {
        jcl.destroyApplet();
    }
    public String action1() {
        return ((MyApplet) jcl.getApplet()).action1(); // <-- ClassCastException
    }
    public int action2() {
        return ((MyApplet) jcl.getApplet()).action2(); // <-- ClassCastException
    }
}
```

My changes to JarClassLoader.java:

```
public class JarClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private Applet applet; // was JApplet

    public JarClassLoader() {
        this(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    }

    public JarClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);

        ...
    }

    public void initApplet(String sClass, final Applet appletParent) { // 2nd arg was JApplet
        Class<?> clazz = loadClass(sClass);
        applet = (Applet) clazz.newInstance();
        ...
    }

    public Applet getApplet() {
        return applet;
    }
    ...
```

In my opinion it is clear that the instance of MyAppletLauncher cannot down cast the provided Applet instance to MyApplet because the MyApplet instance was created in a different namespace (= not by the same class loader). But my issue here is how do I get the action1() and action2() calls to the MyApplet object? Or more common, can I call the public interface of MyApplet from the MyAppletLauncher object?

I already tried several things, like

- MyApplet implements MyInterface, and then cast to MyInterface
- Change the type of member JarClassLoader.applet to MyApplet

But all result in a ClassCastException at some point.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of the launcher applet.  It serves as a shim between the applet container and its system ClassLoader on one hand, and the JCL-loaded real applet and JCL on the other.  There should be nothing in the launcher applet besides the applet lifecycle methods.

I am unsure how any methods other than lifecycle methods are being invoked on your launcher applet anyway.  That can't be accidental, so just stop trying to do it.  Implement all your applet's functionality in the real applet class and any helper classes you need, as if the launcher applet didn't exist.

If you must have external components looking up your applet and invoking methods on it, then modify or subclass JCL to provide additional shim methods, using the same model that it already uses for application lifecycle methods.

Comment: Maybe the applet needs to accept calls from Javascript?

Comment: That is right biziclop, I call action1() and action2() directly from Javascript.

Comment: Javascript calling applet methods usually turns out to be quite a mess, but yes, I suppose that could be what's happening.  I guess other applets could be doing the same (also a mess).

Comment: Edited to add advice for the case of exposing an interface to external components.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with additional shim methods. Are you suggesting that I add action1() and action2() to (a subclass of) JCL and then let the JCL call start()/stop() within these methods? The point here is that I need data from the webpage into the applet AND the result (which might be a lot of data) back to the webpage. I can set parameters (like I use <PARAM> in my webpage) prior to start() but I cannot get data back from it, can I?

Comment: A shim method would be one built on the same model as `JarClassLoader.initApplet()` *et. al.*.  You would use it the same way you use the other shim methods: by putting an appropriate method on the launcher applet that delegates to the JCL (subclass).  In principle you could add just one method to JCL if that method relies on reflection to dispatch the call.

Answer (score 0):

We can't see that part of your code but if your `JarClassLoader` chains to the parent class loader correctly (which it probably doesn't), then the interface solution should work. Provided that the interface is loaded by the main class loader and not from the custom external jars.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
public void init() {
    jcl = new JarClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    jcl.initApplet("MyApplet", this);
}
```

And `JarClassLoader` should call [the appropriate super constructor of `ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#ClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)). This way any classes that can be loaded by the "main" class loader will only be loaded once, so the cast to an interface should work.

**Update:** If there's no way to get around `JarClassLoader`s non-delegating behaviour, your next best option is reflection. It isn't nice but at least it works.

```
public void action1() {
    Applet applet = jcl.getApplet();
    Method action = applet.getClass().getDeclaredMethod( "action1" );
    action.invoke( applet );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that `JarClassLoader` *does not* delegate properly to its parent `ClassLoader` (which is `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` by default) because the documented limitations include that it may load system classes from locations other than the system's built-in library.  Nasty.

Comment: It's conceivable that the interface solution would work anyway, though.

Comment: In that case, reflection.

Comment: I added the JCL constructors to the source code above ;). I will try to pass the parent class loader as you suggest and see if this works.

Comment: I called the JCL constructor as you suggested, but still that nasty cast exception. Even when I explicitly load the interface class before instantiating the JCL `this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("MyInterface");`, I get the exception.

Comment: @EelkodeGroot John Bollinger found the reason why: `JarClassLoader` doesn't delegate correctly (and apparently this is a feature, not a bug). I would suggest reflection then. It's nasty but it'll get the job done. I'll update my answer with it.

Comment: When I use getDeclaredMethod() I get a SecurityException.  java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
 at MyAppletLauncher.action1(...

Comment: @EelkodeGroot You need to grant that permission to your applet, as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#permissions